# C++ using assert for class?

Tags: c++, assert

I read some posts about `assert` and after all I can only imagine the following usage as legitime:

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class( Requirement* aRequirement )
    : m_Requirement( aRequirement )
    {
    }

    // ...

    void doSomething()
    {
        // Theoretically it is always set, but it is
        // possible that a messy user passed a null pointer.
        assert( m_Requirement != nullptr );

        // ...
    }

    // ...

private:
    Requirement* m_Requirement;
};
```

So using an assert is legitime when theoretically a variable is valid, but it is possible that a messy user passes some inappropriate value.

- For example if we want to check a range then we should not use `assert` or `exception`, just use conditionals.
- If there can be exceptional cases then `exceptions` shall be used.
- And here is the question ... when everything shall be correct is that the exact time when the `assert` shall be used ?
- Is that correct ?
- Or is there any other cases when `assert` shall be used ?

Comment: If the argument passed to the construction is not _optional_ consider using a reference instead of a pointer. Since null references do not exist in C++ you can eliminate the null pointer check in your other functions. If yuo want to continue using a pointer you should check for null in the constructor and throw an exception if it is null.

Comment: It sounds good. But is there any case when an assert should be used ?

Comment: The common usage is for contracts (think preconditions and postconditions). However, C++ should be getting some actual contracts support before too long.

Comment: For me it seems that the pointer in the example is a precondition, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Exceptions are for exceptional but recoverable errors from the outside, assertions are for bug-catching on the inside.

`assert()` is here to trap things that **shouldn't** happen, in any condition, if the program is correct. The goal is to halt the program for analysis as soon as it gets into an impossible state, before it goes haywire and crashes somewhere else, garbles the stack, or any other hard-to-debug failure.

You should use assertions to check that functions are fed the correct parameters (to catch the user's errors), that algorithms work the way they're intended to (to catch your own errors), etc.

Exceptions are here to trap thing that *may* (and will someday) happen, and that are not under any programmer's control, like network failure, memory shortage, file I/O problems, etc. They're an error handling facility, which provide an alternative code path for them.

You should use them to communicate errors to somewhere you can handle them. For example, a memory exception thrown from the bottom of a client-handling procedure could fly back up and be caught by the main server procedure, which would then gracefully notify the client and close its connection and continue working normally.

Answer (score 0):

> - Is that correct ?

There's no finite (or standard defined) *correct* way of using `assert()`

> - Or is there any other cases when assert shall be used ?

IMHO it shouldn't really be used at all in preference of throwing an exception.
I personally hate `assert()` (vs. exceptions thrown).

It's hard to debug, unless you install your own `abort()` handler and can place breakpoints there.

Also `assert()` is only active with debug builds, and may lead to UB in production programs, where they've not been caught with test suites running on the debug version.

Comment: All the problems you mentioned can be solved by using a custom assert (e.g.: `my_assert`). You can throw an exception, enable them in release builds and so on...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath While you're actually right, meh I don't like it. There's no need for `assert()`.

Comment: Personally I prefer asserts, they better convey the *intention* (and as I said, you can always change the actual *behaviour*). See @Quentin 's answers for details.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If `assert()` isn't used the right way, it will make (debugging) life harder, while exceptions always allow debugging smoothly to the actual point of failure.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what do you mean, they may lead to UB ? An `assert` placed to protect against UB, and the UB-causing case never getting tested before relase ?

Comment: @Quentin I referred to the fact, that `assert()` actually deceases to NOP (and thus does't protect anything) in case of  `NDEBUG` is defined.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Anything used the wrong way will make your life harder. And it's pointless to argue about the behaviour, when you can change it with a wrapper....

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No quantity of debugging facilities can save you if you don't actually test the use case that would cause the bug. Though I admit the whole assert/exceptions system has been designed for a perfect world where all tests are comprehensive.